# Grouping DateTime by hour in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in my database which contains a column called DateTimes. This column has DateTime data inside it which I would like to select the different hours for which this table has data for. For example, if the column has these entries:

```
2015-05-03 01:06:45
2015-05-03 04:51:09
2015-05-03 05:08:11
2015-05-03 09:33:35
2015-05-03 13:46:38
```

I would like to return

```
2015-05-03 01:00:00
2015-05-03 04:00:00
2015-05-03 05:00:00
2015-05-03 09:00:00
2015-05-03 13:00:00
```

I have tried the following which is returning an error:

```
SELECT DateTimes
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, DateTimes)
```

I feel like this should be easy to do but I can't seem to get it right (I'm very new to SQL). I'm using MS SQL Management Studio 2012 to access my database.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: The error is: Column 'MyTable.DateTimes' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thank you everyone who helped out! Lots of really good answers but alas I can only choose one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Test Data:

```
DECLARE @MyTable AS TABLE(DateTimes DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @MyTable(DateTimes)
VALUES('2015-05-03 01:06:45')
,('2015-05-03 04:51:09')
,('2015-05-03 05:08:11')
,('2015-05-03 09:33:35')
,('2015-05-03 13:46:38')
```

Query:

```
  SELECT Hourly
    FROM (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, DateTimes), 0) AS Hourly
            FROM @MyTable) AS DatesAsHours
GROUP BY Hourly
```

Results:

```
Hourly
2015-05-03 01:00:00.000
2015-05-03 04:00:00.000
2015-05-03 05:00:00.000
2015-05-03 09:00:00.000
2015-05-03 13:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was after for my returned information

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
SELECT DateTimes
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, DateTimes), DateTimes;
```

You were simply missing the DateTimes field directly in your group by.

Also, from the rest of your question, you may want to do the following:

```
SELECT FORMAT(DateTimes, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:00:00', 'en-US')
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, DateTimes), FORMAT(DateTimes, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:00:00', 'en-US');
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense! I've just tried the query now and it has returned the correct column heading, but the column is empty.

Comment: Does the table contain data?

Comment: Thank you for this. My table did contain data however your comment prompted me to check if I was looking at the correct database (I wasn't :p). After amending that your query worked

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is to Format your date , so it hides minutes/seconds,

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), DateTimes, 100) FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the formatting in the select.  Doing DATEPART in Group By will cause rows with the same hour to be in the same group.  Also, DATEPART only returns the hour part of the datetime.

You can try using DATE_FORMAT function, like:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(DateTimes, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") from MyTable
```

See man page for DATE_FORMAT for available formatting options.

Comment: This would be the ideal outcome. I tried a previous solution using DATE_FORMAT which yielded the same result as your suggestion; 'DATE_FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name'. I've been unable to find a working alternative so far.

Comment: Sorry.  I think function name is just FORMAT.  [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/21/sql-server-display-datetime-in-specific-format-sql-in-sixty-seconds-033-video/)